# ios 7 showing alert view in viewDidAppear causes view to not appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm pushing a view on to my navigation controller -

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_gameOverViewController animated:YES];
```

In the new view's `viewDidAppear`, I show an alert view -

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"alert title"
                           message:@"some text"
                           delegate:self
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Rate It!"
                           otherButtonTitles:@"No Thanks",
                           @"Don't ask again", nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
```

In iOS 6 and earlier this works fine.  The 'gameOver' view is visible behind the alert view.  Once the alert view is dismissed the game over view is visible.  In iOS 7, the alert view shows over the previous view. When the alert view is dismissed, the previous view is still visible.  The 'gameOver' view is never presented to the user.

Is there a better way to show `UIAlertView` in iOS 7?

Comment: It sounds like it should work, what error message do you get when it crashes?

Comment: You should really switch to ARC...

Comment: I investigated the error.  It's an unrelated error caused by trying to load some data beyond the bounds of an array.  Hitting the end of the array is what triggered the "gameOver" view to load.   So it looks like the gameOver view has just been popped from the navigationcontroller stack.

Comment: Can you answer your own question then, and accept it? That way people don't keep reading it, thinking you still need help.

Comment: i do still need help.. the gameover view is never shown.  I do not pop the view off the controller and yet that is what happens.. i will edit the original question to clarify

Comment: Your code works fine for me in viewDidAppear. The pushed view shows, and then the alert view is presented. How are you creating the instance of _gameOverViewController that you push?

Comment: I agree with @rdelmar .. I would switch to ARC and use storyboards for pushing and testing what's going on...

Comment: If you remove the `UIAlertView` call, does it work? We need to see more related code.

Answer (score 1):

It came down to popping a view off the navigationcontroller and pushing a new one on at the same time.  in ios6 and below this worked fine.  in ios7 it appears that you cant push a new view onto the stack until the previous animation has stopped.